# How to implement Auth0 in Unity Game Engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am creating an app using Unity Game Engine and want to use the Auth0 service for the User Management. I am writing my API in .Net and I can able to read the claims in the API side. I am unable to find any Auth0 library to register and login the User. Is there any way to do it?